# How to change location of the HTML element?

Tags: html, css

Here is code:

```
    <div id="txtSelectedEmails">
    </div>
    @Html.TextBox("SubjectTextArea", string.Empty, new { id = "txtMailSubject", placeholder = "Subject" })
    @Html.TextArea("MessageTextArea", string.Empty, new { id = "txtMessageArea", placeholder = "Message" })
    @Html.Button("Send", new { onclick = "SendMessage()" })
</div>
```

Here is css code:

```
/* Styles for div with selected emails
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
#txtSelectedEmails
{
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    width: 732px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
}


/* Styles for mail subject Textbox
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
#txtMailSubject
{
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    width: 732px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
}

/* Styles for message TextArea
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
#txtMessageArea
{
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    width: 732px;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

This code generate this design:

[image]

I want the button **send**  appear left under message text box?
How can I implement it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You did not include the HTML that builds what you have in the image. That's important to being able to answer this question. You've included some sort of .NET server-side code, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, all of your text fields have the attribute `float: right;` but your button does not. Putting the button in a container that also contains `float: right;` while the button itself has `float: left;` should do the trick.

You will also need to add `clear: both;` to the container with the button so that the button is underneath the text fields.

Here is an example of what you could do (colored background to show the container and how `float` is being used) :
http://jsfiddle.net/1fp8rrgo/

You could also hard code the position of the button using pixels, which isn't preferred.